# How to train a spaCy language model from scratch?

Tags: spacy

I am still quite a beginner with **spaCy** (although I already do enjoy it). I would like to create a language model for a language still unsupported, that is from scratch. I do have comprehensive text corpora in this language. Where do I start and how to proceed? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

You can start in the official documentacion of spacy : https://course.spacy.io/en

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/84891)

Comment: Link based answer.